# C# Xamarin Forms Populating CollectionView from ViewModel is always null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to populate a collection view from a ViewModel, however when I try to bind the data to the collection view, the ViewModel is null.

xaml.cs file

```
ObservableCollection<ReportsClass> newKidList = new ObservableCollection<ReportsClass>();

        public ReportsViewModel viewmodel { get; set; }

        public ReportsPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            viewmodel = new ReportsViewModel();

            this.BindingContext = viewmodel;

            PreviousDateRange.CornerRadius = 20;
            NextDateRange.CornerRadius = 20;

            DateTime firstDate = currentDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
            DateTime secondDate = currentDate.AddDays(7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Saturday);

            DateRange.Text = firstDate.ToString("MMMM d") + " - " + secondDate.ToString("MMMM d");

            Kids.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(viewmodel.kids));


        }
```

Here is my view model

```
public class ReportsViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<ReportsClass> kids { get; set; }

        FirebaseStorageHelper firebaseStorageHelper = new FirebaseStorageHelper();

        WebServiceClass webServiceClass = new WebServiceClass();

        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

        public ReportsViewModel()
        {
            GetKids();
        }

        public async void GetKids()
        {
            var parentId = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("parentid");

            kids = await webServiceClass.Reports(Convert.ToInt32(parentId), currentDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday), currentDate.AddDays(7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Saturday));

        }
    }
```

And here is the method that gets the data for the view model

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<ReportsClass>> Reports(int parentid, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parentid", parentid.ToString()),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("startDate", startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss")),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("endDate", endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            });

            var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("https://example.com/api/index.php?action=reports"), content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            ObservableCollection<ReportsClass> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ReportsClass>>(responseString);

            return items;

        }
```

What am I doing wrong? The purpose of me doing it this way is so I can update an item in the collectionview

Here is my ReportsClass

```
public class ReportsClass
{

    public ReportsClass(string firstName)
    {
        first_name = firstName;
    }

    public string first_name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: learn how to use xaml bindings on forms. way easier there

Comment: example of this?

Comment: don't call async code from the constructor.  Use INPC on your VMs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION A:**

1. Fix the syntax of `Kids.SetBinding`, to not get `null`. Refer to the CLASS `ReportsViewModel`, not to the INSTANCE `viewmodel`:

```
    Kids.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(ReportsViewModel.kids));
```

2. The kids still won't appear in list. To fix, `kids` needs `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> kids {
        get => _kids;
        set {
            _kids = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _kids;
```

3. See the other code in Option B. Adapt as desired.
4. When you need XAML to see a DYNAMIC change, you need [OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.onpropertychanged?view=xamarin-forms). This is an implementation of [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0). Add this call to properties (that XAML binds to) of ReportsClass:

```
// Inheriting from `BindableObject` is one way to obtain OnPropertyChanged method.
public class ReportsClass : Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject
{

    public ReportsClass(string firstName)
    {
        first_name = firstName;
    }

    public string first_name {
        get => _first_name;
        set {
            _first_name = value;
            // This tells XAML there was a change.
            // Makes "{Binding first_name}" work dynamically.
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _first_name;

}
```

---

**OPTION B:**

Didn't find an answer anywhere that does everything correctly, so here is a complete sample, for future reference:

1. Remove `Kids.SetBinding(...)`. (It can be fixed as shown in OPTION A, but its easier to get it correct in XAML, so below I show it in XAML.)
2. `Binding`s from Page to VM. See `xaml` below.
3. Create `ObservableCollection` with setter that does `OnPropertyChanged`. This informs XAML when the list is ready, so page updates. (This is an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, as Jason mentioned.)
4. Use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async ()` to create an `async` context, that is *queued* to run after constructor returns. (This fixes the issue Jason mentioned, which is that a constructor isn't an `async` context, so should not DIRECTLY call an `async` method such as `QueryItemsAsync`, or your `GetKids`.) This is more reliable.

PageWithQueryData.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestXFUWP.PageWithQueryData">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="Loading ..." FontSize="24" TextColor="Blue" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </CollectionView.EmptyView>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

PageWithQueryData.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class PageWithQueryData : ContentPage
{
    public PageWithQueryData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ... other initialization work here ...
        // BUT remove `Kids.Binding(...);` line. See XAML: `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`.

        BindingContext = new VMWithQueryData();
    }
}
```

VMWithQueryData.cs:

```
class VMWithQueryData : Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject
{
    public VMWithQueryData()
    {
        // Start an async task to query.
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            await QueryItemsAsync();
        });

        // Alternative implementation: Start a background task to query.
        //QueryItemsInBackground();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items {
        get => _items;
        set {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _items;


    private async Task QueryItemsAsync()
    {
        var names = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
        bool queryOneAtATime = false;// true;
        if (queryOneAtATime) {
            // Show each item as it is available.
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
            foreach (var name in names) {
                // Simulate slow query - replace with query that returns one item.
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Items.Add(new ItemModel(name));
            }
        } else {
            // Load all the items, then show them.
            // Simulate slow query - replace with query that returns all data.
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            var items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
            foreach (var name in names) {
                items.Add(new ItemModel(name));
            }
            Items = items;
        }
    }

    // Alternative implementation, using a background thread.
    private void QueryItemsInBackground()
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
            var names = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
            bool queryOneAtATime = false;// true;
            if (queryOneAtATime) {
                // Show each item as it is available.
                Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
                foreach (var name in names) {
                    // Simulate slow query - replace with query that returns one item.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Items.Add(new ItemModel(name));
                }
            } else {
                // Load all the items, then show them.
                // Simulate slow query - replace with query that returns all data.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                var items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
                foreach (var name in names) {
                    items.Add(new ItemModel(name));
                }
                Items = items;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ItemModel.cs:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This also demonstrates `<CollectionView.EmptyView>` to display a message to user, while the data is being queried.

For completeness, I've included an alternative `QueryItemsInBackground`, that uses a background thread instead of an `async` method. Either approach works well.

Notice inheritance from `Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject`. This is one way to get an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. You can use any other MVVM library or technique.

Comment: An alternative approach is to query the data BEFORE creating the page. Then pass the data to a static "Create" method. [Shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70327696/199364).

Comment: Hi, Yes now my collectionview is being populated, but when I try this: viewmodel.kids[0].first_name = "Joe"; the first_name does not change on the UI

Comment: @user979331 - that means a change is needed to inform the xaml of the change. Add to question the source for `ReportsClass`. Most importantly, the class declaration `public class ReportsClass : ?anything-you-inherit-from-here?` and the declaration of `first_name` - it will need `OnPropertyChanged` similar to `Items`.

Comment: I added my ReportsClass

Comment: @user979331 - I added the fixed ReportsClass to my answer. Option A, step (4).

Answer (score 1):

Move this line of code to the end of your constructor

```
this.BindingContext = viewmodel;
```

Comment: First you need to set binding to each `View` by `SetBinding` end after you finish setup all of the stuff you just set `this.BindingContext`. As far as I saw, it will not break you constructor because there are no line that call `viewmodel`