# Dynamically pass argument to a BindingContext in Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to populate a custom ListView with data from a downloaded JSON.

This is the custom ListView I created:

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="5" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TradeDate}"  Padding="25,0,0,0" FontSize="19" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TradeGain}" Padding="0,0,25,0" FontSize="19" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TradeQty}" Padding="25,0,0,0" FontSize="16"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TradeEff}" Padding="0,0,25,0" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Then I set the BindingContext to the class with the ItemSource:

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:TradesView>
            <x:Arguments>
                <x:String>cacca</x:String>
            </x:Arguments>
        </local:TradesView>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

This is the TradeView class seen here in the BindingContext:

Unfortunately, I can't download the JSON from here since it requires authentication which of course is handled by another ContentPage.

```
public class TradesView
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
        public TradesView(string trades)
        {
            Trades = new ObservableCollection<Trade>();
            JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(trades);
            foreach (JObject trade  in jArray){
                Trades.Add(new Trade(trade["date"].ToString(), trade["gain"].ToString(), trade["depth"].ToString(), "0"));
            }
            

        }
    }
```

The problem is that now I have no idea on how to proceed since there seems no way of passing a variable as an argument to the TradeView constructor which should handle the JSON and populate the ObservableCollection with what I need.

I just think my procedure is wrong and I should scrap a lot of what I did, but then I genuinely have no idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Step back to an earlier point in your code. What page is TradeView in? Do you have a method where you create that page, after authentication? Please show that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this. Here is one, which uses a "Factory method" (`Create`) to create the **page** that contains your view, then set that page's `Items` property.

This makes sense if there is only one page that contains that view.

Usage:

```
var names = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
MainPage = SelfBoundPageWithCollection.Create(names);
```

SelfBoundPageWithCollection.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestXFUWP.SelfBoundPageWithCollection">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SelfBoundPageWithCollection.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class SelfBoundPageWithCollection : ContentPage
{
    public SelfBoundPageWithCollection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items {
        get => _items;
        set {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _items;


    public static SelfBoundPageWithCollection Create(List<string> names)
    {
        var it = new SelfBoundPageWithCollection();
        it.FillItems(names);
        return it;
    }

    // Can call this directly later, to replace Items collection.
    public void FillItems(List<string> names)
    {
        var items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        foreach (var name in names) {
            items.Add(new ItemModel(name));
        }
        Items = items;
    }
}
```

---

**Or to have a separate "ViewModel" (MVVM),** do it like this:

Usage:

```
var names = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
MainPage = PageWithCollection.Create(names);
```

PageWithCollection.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class PageWithCollection : ContentPage
{
    public PageWithCollection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModelWithItems();
    }


    public static PageWithCollection Create(List<string> names)
    {
        var it = new PageWithCollection();

        var vm = (ViewModelWithItems)it.BindingContext;
        vm.FillItems(names);

        return it;
    }
}
```

ViewModelWithItems.cs:

```
public class ViewModelWithItems : Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject
{
    public ViewModelWithItems()
    {
    }


    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items {
        get => _items;
        set {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _items;


    public void FillItems(List<string> names)
    {
        var items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        foreach (var name in names) {
            items.Add(new ItemModel(name));
        }
        Items = items;
    }
}
```

---

**Both of the above refer to this model:**

ItemModel.cs:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This indeed solved it.
I decided to go with the first option (even if the second looks more elegant) because I figured out it was easier to implement.

Thank you.